# JMeter report shows 3 results for one request

Tags: jmeter, report

I installed JMeter 5.3, created one thread group with 10/10/10 (users/rampup time/loop count), so I expect to get 100 requests executed total and see graph with one line which will show how long requests take, BUT I see that 300 requests were executed and my report dashboard looks like this:

```
SomeRequest     100 0   0.00%   1570.50 1118    1900    1684.50 1892.90 1900.00 1900.00 4.85    29.62   1.91
SomeRequest-0   100 0   0.00%   344.50  305 405 337.50  403.20  405.00  405.00  13.14   6.71    2.59
SomeRequest-1   100 0   0.00%   1225.30 812 1494    1345.50 1492.40 1494.00 1494.00 6.04    33.78   1.19
```

And graph shows 3 lines instead of one.

So my question: why do I see 3 lines instead of one? Why test was executed 3 times? Maybe I'm missing some global config property which is set to "3"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be 2 possible reasons:

1. Your server [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) you somewhere so you see these extra requests as redirect targets (like from HTTP to HTTPS, from landing page to language-specific page, etc)

   [image]

   like here:

   [image]
2. You have [Retrieve all embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) option enabled on "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler so JMeter parses the response and downloads extra data like images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.

   [image]

Most probably the behaviour is valid, if you want to check the URL for the sub-requests you can run your test in GUI mode with `Functional test mode` option enabled on Test Plan level - this way you will be able to see the URLs for the secondary requests:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I played with "auto redirect" and "follow redirects" and now understand why I see several requests: "follow redirects" reports all requests to log, so I'm getting 3 of them because of 2 redirects.